# Missing required parameter: name when using solr CREATEALIAS

Tags: solrcloud

I submitted a reqest to my solr cloud server with curl:

```
curl http://solrserver1:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=bf&collections=collection1,collection2
```

It return a 400 error and said: Missing required parameter: name. But you see in the command line I really provided a name parameter.

I saw several post online talking about CREATEALIAS action, so I think it must be some mistake of myself. My solr server is version 4.6.1

Could anyone know what's the reason ?

Answer (score 8):

Should add quotes like this:

```
curl "http://solrserver1:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=bf&collections=collection1,collection2"
```

It works and return status 0

Comment: syan, thank you for the small tip. It helped me a lot. I missed the simple step and was trying to see for the complicated areas.

Answer (score 0):

Following commands worked:

```
$ bin/solr create_collection -c techproducts -d _default -n techproducts -shards 2 -replicationFactor 2 -V
```

The output shows the rest api url

```
$ curl http://localhost:7574/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=techproducts&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=-1&collection.configName=techproducts
```